# Plugin not working on live site

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Estro WordPress plugin for my slider. When I make the website live it shows me this message in every page of my website:

> "404 Not Found
>   The resource requested could not be found on this
>   server!
>   Powered By Acme Web Server Acme Technologies is not
>   responsible for administration and contents of this web site!"

```
<?php
    // plugin admin class 
    class PeUtilsImage {
        function getThumb($img,$width,$height,$crop) {

            $paths = wp_upload_dir();
            $img = str_replace($paths["baseurl"],"",$img);
            $img = $paths['basedir'].$img;

            if (!$img || !($target = @filemtime($img))) return false;

            $info = pathinfo($img);
            $dir = $info['dirname'];
            $ext = $info['extension'];


            $thumb = "$dir/".wp_basename($img, ".$ext")."-{$width}x{$height}.{$ext}";
            if (!($dest = @filemtime($thumb)) || $dest < $img) {
                $thumb = image_resize($img,$width,$height,$crop);
            }
            return $thumb;

        }
    }
?>
```

see this is the code...frome where the image path comes..i think it should work correctly...

Comment: Check the source code, have a look at the URL's that it is trying to load. Perfect example, local to live. Sometimes wordpress saves the full URL (ie: `http://localhost/wp-upload/image/image1.jpg`) instead of just the path (ie: `/wp-upload/image/image1.jpg`).

Comment: hay..anybody please help..i am not detting any solution...

Answer (score 1):

If your Wordpress plugin is getting images from posts you just have to use :

```
 $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
 <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" alt="Text_2" />
```

Or if you're trying to set a special image from your upload folder i suggest you to use :

```
 <?php $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir(); ?>
 <?php echo $upload_dir['baseurl']; ?>
```

Let's check : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir

Comment: thank you for your reply...but i have tried this but this is already given in the plugin..if you want to see ..."weddingsplanner.co.in/test"..is the URL...

Answer (score 0):

Replace...

wp-config.php file 's define('WP_DEBUG', false);

part with

// Turns WordPress debugging on

define('WP_DEBUG', true);

// Tells WordPress to log everything to the /wp-content/debug.log file

define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

// Doesn't force the PHP 'display_errors' variable to be on

define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);

// Hides errors from being displayed on-screen

@ini_set('display_errors', 0);

Then run the project in live server it will give you error in log file check it in wp-content/debug.log file and do appropriate